# Laravel resource route doesn't display show in controller

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

En el archivo rutas, estoy definiendo una ruta tipo recursos

Route::resource('dentistas',DentistaController::class);

En el archivo controller estoy definiendo dos métodos el método índex que si me va bien y el create que es donde tengo el problema, cuando en el índex, cliqueo el botón de crear, este se me muestra en blanco, este es mi archivo controlador.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class DentistaController extends Controller
{
   /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(){
        $dentista =User::all();
        return view('dentistas.index', compact('dentista'));
    }

     /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function crear(){
        return view('dentistas.crear');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Este es el archivo crear.blade

```
@extends('layouts.panel')

@section('content')
      <div class="card shadow">
        <div class="card-header border-0">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
              <h3 class="mb-0">Nuevo dentista</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col text-right">
              <a href="{{url('/dentistas')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                Regresar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            {{-- definimos una condicion para mostrar los mensajes de los errores --}}
            @if ($errors->all())
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $errores)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                        <strong>Error -> </strong> {{$errores}}

                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
            <form action="{{url('/dentistas')}}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name"> Nombre del dentista</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name"class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce el nombre del tratamiento" required  value="{{old('name')}}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email"> Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce la descripcion del tratamiento" value="{{old('email')}}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dni"> DNI</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dni" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce la fecha del tratamiento" value="{{old('dni')}}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="direccion"> Direccion del dentista</label>
                    <input type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce el numero de piezas del producto" value="{{old('piezas')}}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="direccion"> Telefono del dentista</label>
                    <input type="number" name="direccion" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce el numero de piezas del producto" value="{{old('piezas')}}"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Crear nuevo dentista</button>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>

@endsection
```

Y este es el archivo index.blade donde tengo el botón crear a un nuevo dentista en el cual cuando voy a pulsar se abre una ventana en blanco y no aparece nada

```
@extends('layouts.panel')

@section('content')
      <div class="card shadow">
        <div class="card-header border-0">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
              <h3 class="mb-0">Dentistas</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col text-right">
              <a href="{{url('/dentistas/crear')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Nuevo dentista</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{-- <div class="card-body">
            @if (session('notificaciones'))
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    {{session('notificaciones')}}
                </div>
            @endif
        </div> --}}
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <!-- Projects table -->
          <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
            <thead class="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID Dentista</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
                <th scope="col">Correo</th>
                <th scope="col">DNI</th>
                <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($dentista as $datosDentista)
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{$datosDentista->id}}
                  </th>
                <th>
                  {{$datosDentista->name}}
                </th>
                <td>
                    {{$datosDentista->telefonoDentista}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$datosDentista->email}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$datosDentista->dni}}
                  </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{url('/dentistas/'.$datosDentista->id)}}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <a href="{{url('/dentistas/'.$datosDentista->id.'/editar')}}" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Editar</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
                    </form>

                </td>
              </tr>

              @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Pero esas urls `url('/dentistas/crear')` y `url('/dentistas/'.$datosDentista->id.'/editar')` no están definidas en las rutas. Tendrías que hacer que coincidan con las urls que genera tu ruta `Route::resource('dentistas',DentistaController::class);` [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers). O puedes usar el helper `route()` en vez de `url()`, para usar el nombre de la ruta, en vez de su uri

Comment: Si tienes razón, lo acabo de comentar, pero tampoco me funciona la vista crear

Answer (score 0):

Las rutas resource utilizan los métodos del controlador según el método http usado en la petición por ejemplo:

usaremos la ruta **http://tuSitio.com/dentistas**  si se accede mediante

**GET**     usará **DentistaController::index**
**POST**    usará **DentistaController::create**
**PUT**     Usará **DentistaController::update**
**DELETE**  usará **DentistaController::destroy**

esto es útil cuando trabajamos con API's

de la manera en la que tu lo estás haciendo es que intentas acceder a la ruta **http://tuSitio.com/dentistas/crear** sin embargo está no existe.
si no utilizaras API REST te recomiendo que crees una ruta por cada acción que quieres realizar, y a estas le pongas un alias para que puedas obtener la dirección de la ruta con el helper **route()**